# Menu items do not "open" when mouse hover over them?

Tags: themes, css

I am using "basic magazine" wootheme, and for some reason my top menu navigation bar doesn't "open" when I hover the mouse above it:

http://www.danceinisrael.com/

Is there some CSS problem there? How can I detect/fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the superfish menu plugin or is it with the theme itself?

Comment: It is a part of the theme itself

Comment: In fact the hover menu works when you turn off Javascript. There's something with the superfish script or CSS that is breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the superfish menu plugin is not setting the CSS properties correctly when hovering over the menu item. You can fix this by updating the CSS in your styles.css file at line 155 from:

```
.nav2 li.sfHover ul, ul.nav2 li:hover ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B3B3B3;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

to:

```
.nav2 li.sfHover ul, ul.nav2 li:hover ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B3B3B3;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: visible!important;
    display: block!important;
}
```

This overrides the visibility and display settings that are being set inline on the element itself by superfish.js, but are not being cleared when you hover over the menu item.

Comment: Thanks ZweiBlumen - this totally fixed the problem.  How did you manage to find this solution?  Thanks again!

Comment: Firebug to the rescue: http://getfirebug.com/